# Boto3 put_object() fails when I am using SSECustomerKey

Tags: python, boto3, ceph, radosgw

I have been trying for the past day to load some encrypted text to a Ceph object storage, but whenever I try, I get the following error:

*botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation: Unknown*

The code I am using is this:

```
random_key = os.urandom(32)

s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
              Key=KEY,
              Body='the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
              SSECustomerKey=random_key,
              SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256'
              )
```

I am mentioning that if I remove `SSECustomerKey=random_key,SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256'`
then it loads the text.

Comment: I created a fresh new bucket with the default settings, and I tried your code snippet. The PutObject action succeeded.

Comment: Have you uploaded this to Ceph?

Comment: No, I uploaded it to S3.

Comment: Okay. I think this might be a Ceph related problem. I need to find a way to talk to the devs so I can test my setup..

Comment: @Rm4n this was a long time ago and I am not sure if this is right, but I thing that I have replaced the put_object function with upload_fileobj:

s3.upload_fileobj(file, name, file.filename, ExtraArgs={"ContentType": file.content_type})

You can see a basic interface that worked two years ago on my GitHub:
https://github.com/AlexNisulescu/WebInterface-for-s3/tree/master